# JS - converts objects to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have following array of objects:

```
[{"CZ-PR":"1"},{"CZ-JC":"0"},{"CZ-JM":"0"},{"CZ-KA":"0"},{"CZ-VY":"0"},{"CZ-KR":"0"},{"CZ-LI":"0"},{"CZ-MO":"0"},{"CZ-OL":"0"},{"CZ-PA":"0"},{"CZ-PL":"0"},{"CZ-ST":"0"},{"CZ-US":"0"},{"CZ-ZL":"0"}]
```

I need to convert it to array of arrays, like this (need to pass it to Google Maps Geocharts constructor):

```
[["CZ-PR","1"],["CZ-JC","0"]]
```

I tried:

```
var arr = [];
for (var k in obj) arr.push([+k, obj[k]]);
```

Which gives me array for each letter... How can I convert my initial object to what I need?

EDIT:
The format that is expected from Google geocharts is this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);
```

Comment: this is a `SyntaxError`: `[["CZ-PR":"1"],["CZ-JC":"0"]]`

Comment: Hmmm, this is what Geocharts expect: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Comment: @user1049961 ????????

Comment: @SantiagoHernández look at the below example it is the correct format he wants he might have just made a typo there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var data = [{"CZ-PR":"1"},{"CZ-JC":"0"},{"CZ-JM":"0"},{"CZ-KA":"0"},{"CZ-VY":"0"},{"CZ-KR":"0"},{"CZ-LI":"0"},{"CZ-MO":"0"},{"CZ-OL":"0"},{"CZ-PA":"0"},{"CZ-PL":"0"},{"CZ-ST":"0"},{"CZ-US":"0"},{"CZ-ZL":"0"}];

var result = [];

result = data.map(function (el) {
    var key = Object.keys(el).pop()

    return [
        key, +el[key]
    ]
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
var objectArray = [{"CZ-PR":"1"},{"CZ-JC":"0"},{"CZ-JM":"0"},{"CZ-KA":"0"},{"CZ-VY":"0"},{"CZ-KR":"0"},{"CZ-LI":"0"},{"CZ-MO":"0"},{"CZ-OL":"0"},{"CZ-PA":"0"},{"CZ-PL":"0"},{"CZ-ST":"0"},{"CZ-US":"0"},{"CZ-ZL":"0"}];

// build data array
var dataArray = objectArray.map(function(e) { 
    var key = Object.keys(e).pop();
    return [key,e[key]];
});

// add the headers!
dataArray.unshift(['Country', 'Popularity']);

// pass data to google
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    dataArray
);
```

luck!

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!

Comment: @user1049961 no problem :P

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrObj = [{"CZ-PR":"1"},{"CZ-JC":"0"},{"CZ-JM":"0"},{"CZ-KA":"0"},{"CZ-VY":"0"},{"CZ-KR":"0"},{"CZ-LI":"0"},{"CZ-MO":"0"},{"CZ-OL":"0"},{"CZ-PA":"0"},{"CZ-PL":"0"},{"CZ-ST":"0"},{"CZ-US":"0"},{"CZ-ZL":"0"}];
var thisArr = [];
const result = arrObj.reduce((acc, thisObj) => {
    thisArr = [];
    for(let val in thisObj) {
        thisArr.push(val)
      thisArr.push(thisObj[val])
      acc.push(thisArr);
      }
      return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).